# Violation of the second law of thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, perpetual-motion

Here is a machine which seems to violate the second law of thermodynamics:
[image: 2 confocal ellipsoids and an annulus]

- $A$ and $B$ are point black bodies of the **same** temperature (*initially*).
- everything is rotationally symmetric around the axis $AB$
- $e$ and $f$ are ellipsoids with foci $A$ and $B$, made of a reflective material
- $CD$ and $EF$ are sections of a reflective annulus
- there is no air

The stable state of the machine is $A$ having **higher** temperature than $B$ because

- The heat radiated by $B$ is all absorbed by $A$ (via paths $B\rightarrow K\rightarrow A$ and $B\rightarrow J\rightarrow A$).
- The heat radiated by $A$ is either absorbed by $B$ (via paths $A\rightarrow K\rightarrow B$ and $A\rightarrow J\rightarrow B$) *OR* by $A$ (via paths $A\rightarrow G\rightarrow I\rightarrow A$)

This seems to violate the 2nd law.

So, where is the hole here?

PS. While point bodies and perfect mirrors do not exits, note that we have quite a lot of margin here: a huge left ellipsoid and a tiny right ellipsoid will lead to almost 50% of all radiation from $A$ reflecting back to $A$. So, "small" bodies and 90%-efficient mirrors should be fine.

Comment: Why downvote? Please explain!

Comment: Perfect mirrors and point blackbodies are not physical.  However, to your point, there may be a more "fundamental" reason.  Someone smarter than I will have to address that.

Comment: @garyp: please see PS

Comment: Could you *explicitly* explain why this would contradict the [second law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_law_of_thermodynamics)? No word games please, calculate the entropies that you claim are violating the law - i.e. where does entropy *decrease* here? (Note that, though you have found a stable state, it is not granted that any initial configuration will actually *reach* that state)

Comment: @ACuriousMind: if I am wrong and the creation of temperature difference does not violate the second law, please do the calculation in an answer and I will gladly accept it! TIA.

Comment: There's a temperature difference. So what? The inside of a "perfect" thermos bottle may well have a different temperature than the outside for infinitely long times, but that doesn't contradict anything, as far as I can see. The second law only states that *entropy does not decrease*.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: here the situation is vastly different from a thermos: the temperature difference _increases_.

Comment: @ACuriousMind - equilibrium states are always characterized by uniform temperature in thermodynamics, see all the references for the statement "The temperature within a system in thermodynamic equilibrium is uniform in space as well as in time" in the ["uniform temperature" section of the "Thermodynamic equilibrium" wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_equilibrium#Uniform_temperature)

Comment: @ACuriousMind - regarding the example of a perfect thermos, I'd guess that the term thermodynamic "system" presupposes there is at least *some* possibility of thermal interaction between all the parts, no matter how small or rare--in this sense a perfect thermos could not really be considered just as the limiting case of a series of increasingly good thermoses, since in each good-but-not-perfect members of the series, there's at least some possibility of heat transfer which allows the temperature to become uniform in the long term.

Comment: Voting to close. This is yet another variant of the ellipsoid paradox in thermodynamics. The resolution is simple: You are assuming point particles. Non-point sources will bathe the entire structure in light. See, for example [Yoder & Adkins, "Resolution of the ellipsoid paradox in thermodynamics." *American Journal of Physics* 79.8 (2011): 811-818.](http://scitation.aip.org/content/aapt/journal/ajp/79/8/10.1119/1.3596430).

Comment: @DavidHammen: so, the answer supplied is actually correct, the only thing missing is the reference you provided. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [radiation thermodynamics paradox](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/69528/radiation-thermodynamics-paradox)

Comment: You voted to close your own question as a duplicate now that you've searched a bit deeper? I'm impressed. (Seriously. I am impressed. That shows character.)

Comment: @DavidHammen: thanks! But why is the question closed as "unclear" and not "duplicate"? I think the question is a perfectly clear dupe!

Comment: @sds - We voted on different things. Last I checked, there was one vote for duplicate, two for off-topic, one for unclear. The last person to vote must have chosen unclear, making it a tie between "unclear" and "off-topic". The last vote wins the tie-breaker. Was your question "unclear"? Not at all. It was quite clear to me. I voted "off-topic" b/c the 2nd law of thermodynamics will stand long after QM and GR are superseded by something even better.

Comment: @DavidHammen: I don't see how the permanence of the 2nd law has any bearing on the question being on/off-topic here. At any rate, I think that closing it as dupe would make more sense - and make the link to the other question more prominent (I am being told to avoid prolonged discussions in the comments, so, I guess, I will check out now). Thanks again.

Comment: This site focuses on mainstream physics. Questions regarding violations of the second law of thermodynamics are generally off-topic because they very, very much go against the mainstream.

Comment: @David Hammen - asking a question about how a setup avoids violating some law is not the same as saying confidently that it *does* violate that law, I assumed the question was sincere and not a rhetorical way of saying "look, I've violated the 2nd law!" Physics textbooks often present "puzzler" questions like these for the purpose of aiding understanding.

Comment: The big side could hold more heat for the same temperature just because it's bigger.  It focus is A but that doesnt mean all heat goes to A.  Instead the entire chamber would be heated to the same temerature as the small chamber then that extra heat would spill to the small chamber making them equal temperatures. I know the chambers are vacuums but I'm talking about convected heat in the form of electromagnetic radiation. Hear me on that one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ingenious.  A and B are small, but they cannot be points.The image of B is magnified at A.  Therefore if A and B are the same size, some of the light from B will miss A.

Comment: Why "The image of B is magnified at A."?

Comment: Can you actually do the calculation with a finite radius $R$ for the black bodies and check that the energy transfer balances out? What about the limit $R\to 0$?

Comment: @sds - that's based on mirror optics--concave parabolic mirrors create magnified virtual images of objects at any position closer than the center of curvature of the mirror (which is at twice the focal length, so your A and B would in this range), see [here](http://fphoto.photoshelter.com/image/I00002NWBTZktBbY) for a photo of what's actually seen in one, and for a ray diagram, see the bottom left illustration at the top of p. 332 in the pdf [here](http://faculty.mint.ua.edu/~pleclair/ph102/Notes/older/ch11_mirrors.pdf) (the object is the blue arrow, the virtual image is the orange arrow)

Comment: @StevenMathey In the limit that $R\rightarrow 0$ Stefan-Boltzmann Law has the emitted power tend to 0. Since this is a universal law for all black bodies, there is no parameter you can tune to keep the finite answer in the limit of zero surface area.

Comment: @StevenMathey - I think a detailed calculation would probably be very laborious, since you need to take into account not only the images of A and B in each parabolic section and the flat section, but also the hall-of-mirrors effect where some of the light from the image of B from the mirror near it misses hitting A and is instead reflected in the mirror near A, creating another image whose size is different from that of the image of B created when the light from B takes a direct path to the mirror near A. I would bet that akrasia's answer is the basic key to the solution though.

Comment: Actually, maybe a simpler approach would be to *start* with the assumption of an equilibrium where not only are A and B the same temperature, but every point on the mirrors is glowing with a blackbody distribution of photons at this temperature, with all the surfaces creating a [photon gas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_gas) at that temperature in the space in between...then maybe you could show that at every point on each surface, the energy at each frequency arriving at that point from other points exactly balances the energy at each frequency that we assumed the point would radiate.

Answer (score 0):

Position yourself on the surface of body A and shoot a ray in any direction. After a certain number of reflections from the mirror surfaces (possibly none) it will hit either body A or body B. Now expand the ray into a very narrow cone, such that all the rays in the cone finish on the same body. Looking into that cone you will see a radiant intensity characteristic of the temperature of that body. This is true regardless of any magnification effect (a consequence of the reciprocity theorem for view factors). And since the same is true for any initial ray the radiant intensity will be uniform in all directions, and characteristic of the temperature of both bodies. So there will be no net heat transfer.

Comment: I don't quite follow this, can you explain where in the argument you made use of the assumption that the entire system has reached equilibrium? If the two bodies start out at different temperatures, both emitting blackbody radiation, it can't be true at the beginning that "there will be no net heat transfer", so either the argument is flawed or there is some step in the argument that makes use of an assumption which is valid if we assume the entire system is already at equilibrium, but not valid otherwise.