# Lens-Mirror systems and conservation of specific intensity

Tags: thermodynamics, optics, conservation-laws, radiation

This came out of [a discussion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/200470/second-law-of-thermodynamics-and-heating-a-blackbody-with-another-blackbody) I started yesterday and a [related discussion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/140949/is-it-possible-to-focus-the-radiation-from-a-black-body-to-make-something-hotter) I found.

I'll recap the problem quickly: Consider two blackbodies, with surface areas $A_1$ and $A_2$ and temperatures $T_1$ and $T_2$. Assume $A_1>A_2$. If I use a lens-mirror system to transfer all the radiation emitted by Blackbody 1 onto Blacbody 2, we must have $T_2>T_1$ as a consequence of $A_1>A_2$. This violates the second law of thermodynamics. The resolution was that we cannot transfer all the heat from Blackbody 1 onto Blackbody 2 precisely because $A_1>A_2$.

A statement made in one of the answers in the [related discussion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/140949/is-it-possible-to-focus-the-radiation-from-a-black-body-to-make-something-hotter) by user @Divergence is "Basically, given any source of light radiating from finite surface to half space, you can never concentrate the entire emitted radiation to a smaller area than the original emitting area."

I've tried to read about this and connect this to [conservation of Etendue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etendue) but I'm having a lot of trouble seeing how to prove this statement. Does anyone have an insight into what forbids a lens-mirror system from concentrating all the emitted radiation from one body onto a smaller surface area?

Comment: Well, the conservation of Etendue pretty much is the answer.  Might help to read up a bit on simple geometric optics & then see how/why you can't make an image w/ greater intensity than the source object.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/88821/is-it-possible-to-build-an-optical-system-that-increases-the-perceived-surface-b/189404#189404